# Clear out RAM after each Picture is taken?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm very new to c# and I have a problem with my program.

I'm trying to write a program that Screen Caps a specific part of my screen every 3 seconds and displays it in a picturebox. But after 5 minutes running my program it uses over 900mb of memory. Is there a method to "sweep" the memory after each picture is displayed? Because I intend to run this program up to 40 minutes at a time.

In my WindowsFormApp I have to buttons. one to start the screengrab timer and the other one to stop it.
I used the Timer Component in the FormDesigner Toolbox to make the timer that counts down that 3 seconds.
And in that timer there is the code to make the picture and to put it in the picturebox.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do the screen grab and dispaly picture in picture box.
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, -1150,50, bitmap.Size);
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap; }
```

When I tried to use the Dispose() command my program just crashed. When it crashed there was a big red X in the picturebox (please keep in mind that I'm very new to c# )

Comment: try disposing it _after_ you load the next picture in your picturebox

Comment: Add `using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {  g.CopyFromScreen(...); pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;}`. It's very important that you dispose of the Graphics object and the previous Image you created.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do the screen grab and dispaly picture in picture box.
    Bitmap bitmap = new 
    Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, -1150,50, bitmap.Size);
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    bitmap.Dispose();
    g. Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this dispose the image in the picturebox?